# How to execute python native script using TensorFlow on Android?

Tags: python, android, tensorflow

I implemented python native script for Linux. It works fine.

I'd like to run it on terminal of Android. However it's impossible to install tensorflow into Android on Termux app due to no support for Android.

What is the most simple solution to run my python script on Android?

- Possible to without modifying python script?
- Need to re-implement as android app?

Comment: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/developing-tensorflow-on-android-phone-cfc4297b676e https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/784
You are asking for some highly specialized toolset. I don't think anyone here can help you with that. You will have to ask them directly and go through the steps they took. It's not trivial and highly experimental.